# Run Liquibase over Wix Embedded MySql

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, liquibase, embedded-database

Currently I have some new modules using Spring Boot and a H2 embedded database for functional testing.

The legacy module works with a lot of Liquibase scripts to construct the whole database.

I was looking to use [Wix Embedded Mysql](https://github.com/wix/wix-embedded-mysql) to make the test database more production-like. After read the docs I did not find anything specific about how to handle scripts using tools like Liquibase or Flyway.

Is it possible to execute a Liquibase goal on this embedded database after his startup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a few days of research, **yes**, there is a way of running Liquibase over Wix Embedded MySQL.

Here is the step by step:

### Configuring Wix Embedded Database

The configuration around Wix is pretty straight forward as described on their [GitHub](https://github.com/wix/wix-embedded-mysql):

```
MysqldConfig config = aMysqldConfig(v5_7_latest)
    .withCharset(UTF8)
    .withPort(3060)
    .withUser("myuser", "mypassword")
    .withTimeZone("America/Sao_Paulo")
    .build();

EmbeddedMysql mysqld = anEmbeddedMysql(config)
    .addSchema("myschema")
    .start();
```

### Liquibase configuration

I have added the [Liquibase maven dependency](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.liquibase/liquibase-core/3.6.3) on my project, so we have access to Liquibase code programmatically, the [API](https://www.liquibase.org/javadoc/index.html) can be found here.

First we have to build a [datasource](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder) and pass to Liquibase find the correct implementation of our database, with the result we can then manipulate the Liquibase object to execute the goals:

```
DataSourceBuilder<?> dataSourceBuilder = DataSourceBuilder.create();

dataSourceBuilder.username(mysqld.getConfig().getUsername());
dataSourceBuilder.password(mysqld.getConfig().getPassword());
dataSourceBuilder.driverClassName(com.mysql.jdbc.Driver.class.getName());
dataSourceBuilder.url("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3060/myschema");

DataSource dataSource = dataSourceBuilder.build();

Database database = DatabaseFactory
                        .getInstance()
                        .findCorrectDatabaseImplementation(
                            new JdbcConnection(dataSource.getConnection()) // Fetch MySQL database implementation
                        );

Liquibase liquibase = new Liquibase("liquibase/mychanges.xml", // Path to liquibase changes
                                    new ClassLoaderResourceAccessor(), 
                                    database);

liquibase.update(new Contexts()); // This execute the liquibase:update on the embedded database
```